# Struggling With JS Promises in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, fetch-api

I'm struggling with the concept of `Promise` in JavaScript. I'm writing a React app that makes a `GET` call out to a separate API service in Java, and I want to store its state in a `useState()` hook. So here's my `fetch` code:

```
const ratingsUrl = "%URL%";
const base64 = require("base-64");
const login = "login";
const password = "password";

function fetchRatings() {
  return fetch(ratingsUrl, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: "Basic " + base64.encode(login + ":" + password),
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

And now I'm trying to store its state in a hook in my page component:

```
function DisplayPage(){
  const [ratings, setRatings] = useState(fetchRatings());

.
.
.
}
```

Now, the data returns but it's in a `Promise`, hence causing errors down the line:

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(20)
```

What I need to do is to initialise the data in a hook and return it in a `Table` so I can map through it. However, whenever I try to do something like

```
ratings.map()
```

I get a TypeError in the console saying `ratings.Map is not a function`.

I'm aware that the `fetch` library returns data asynchronously, but all I really want is for the `PromiseResult` to be stored in a `useState()` hook so I can perform operations on it further down the line.

Comment: `fetchRatings` returns a Promise ... use the Promise methodology you already know to obtain the promised value (i.e. you need to use `.then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` methods return promises. If you directly set the result of a promise in your `setRatings` state variable, you will get a promise.

Typically this would be rewritten something like this:

```
function DisplayPage(){
  const [ratings, setRatings] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {

    fetchRatings
      .then(result => setRatings(result))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));

  }, []);
 
  if (ratings === null) return <div>loading...</div>;
  
  /* .. do your thing .. */

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's solved some of the initial errors- however, when I want to return a `Table` and map through the `ratings` object which has been instantiated earlier, I still get a `ratings.Map` is not a function...

Comment: 1. Returning a loader when ratings is still `null` is necessary like I've done in my example. 2. If ratings is an array, you are probably looking for the `.map` function, not the `.Map` function.

Answer (score 0):

How About  this ,

```
const [ratings, setRatings] =  useState();
useEffect(()=>{
         fetch(ratingsUrl, {
method: "GET",
headers: new Headers({
  Authorization: "Basic " + base64.encode(login + ":" + password),
})}).then((response) => {let res = response.json();
    setRatings(res)
      })
.catch(handleError);
 },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice using the useEffect hook to set initial state.(similar to componentDidMount)

So if the response you expect is for example an array.

```
const [ratings, setRatings] = useState([]);
```

Then in the useEffect hook, update state when you get a response from your fetch request.
That way you can prevent errors if you for example map over ratings in your DOM somewhere before the request is finished.

```
useEffect(){
    fetch(ratingsUrl, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: "Basic " + base64.encode(login + ":" + password),
        }),
    })
    .then((response) => {
         response.json()
    })
    .then(res => setRatings(res))
    .catch(handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the fetch runs asynchronously, you're not going to be able to initialize your state using the immediate result of invoking fetchRatings.

There are, fortunately, a couple of fairly straightforward ways to handle this. You can initialize your state with an empty value and then update it once fetchResults resolves:

```js
function DisplayPage() {
  // initially ratings will be undefined
  const [ratings, setRatings] = useState();

  // update state when fetchResults comes back
  fetchResults().then(response => setRatings(response));

  // ...
```

The above example omits this in the interest of readability, but you'd generally do this via [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) so it runs when your component mounts or when relevant inputs (usually props, known as dependencies for the effect) change:

```js
function DisplayPage() {
  const [ratings, setRatings] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResults().then(response => setRatings(response));
  }, []) // empty dependencies array will cause the effect to run only once, on mount

  // ...
```